# Finite covering of a group by proper subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $n$ a natural number such that ${x}^n = e$ for every $x$ in the group. If $p$ is the smallest prime factor of $n$, show that the group cannot be expressed by a union of $p$ proper subgroups.

The finite case is easy, but I am stuck for the general case.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to prove the claim when $n$ is equal to the exponent of the group. I assume your argument for the finite group case is to notice that any proper subgroup has index at least $p$, and each proper subgroup must contain the identity, so the union of any $p$ proper subgroups has strictly less than $|G|$ elements, and hence cannot cover the group $G$.

The same argument works for the general case with some modification. Consider any proper subgroup $H$ of finite index. The kernel of the action of $G$ on the coset space $G/H$ is the kernel of a map to $S_{[G:H]}$, which is a finite group. Thus, the kernel $N$ is a proper normal subgroup of finite index. Now, any element of $G/N$ has order dividing $n$, so it follows that the smallest prime factor of $[G:N]$, and consequently $[G:H]$, is at least $p$.

Now, assume that $G$ is covered by $p$ (or less) proper subgroups. By the results in section 4 in [this paper](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Neumann54.pdf) by B.H. Neumann, we see that all subgroups of infinite index can be ignored. Now, assuming that the proper subgroups have finite index, there is a normal subgroup of finite index contained in their intersection (using the same idea as before). Once you quotient by this normal subgroup, you are left with a finite group, and the result becomes clear from counting.